# Want to remove respective row on click remove anchor tag

Tags: jquery

I want to remove respective row on click "Remove" anchor tag.

From server response i am getting 1 but when i am trying to remove the parent of parent of anchor tag that is not working.

Here is code

As My Html code is:

```
                           <tr>
                              <td><?php echo $w_value['pro_name']; ?></td>
                              <td><?php echo $w_value['sellingprice']; ?></td>
                              <td><a class="remove_wishlist" href="javascript:;" data-uid="<?php echo $uid;?>" data-pid="<?php echo $w_value['id']; ?>">Remove</td>
                            </tr>
```

And My Ajax Code Is:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".remove_wishlist",function(){

    if(confirm('Are you sure to remove this item.')){

        var pid = jQuery(this).data("pid");
        var uid = jQuery(this).data("uid");
        var urll = WEBSITE_URL+"pages/removewishlist";
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:urll,
           data:{pid:pid,uid:uid},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data == 1){

                    $this.parent().parent("tr").remove();//this is not removing the entire row

                }
            }
        });



    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parents()` instead to traverse back up to parent matching `<tr>` selector. Function `.parent()` will only go one level up the DOM tree, whereas `.parents()` returns a full collection of parents to traverse.

```
$this.parents("tr").remove();
```

Two less likely scenarios:

You may need to reference `jQuery` specifically (and not using `$`) like you do elsewhere in the codeblock:

`var $this = jQuery(this); // was: $(this)`

It might be that your data coming back is not expected format (integer) and so you could try comparison to string '`1'` (maybe you've already tested this, and it's already working the way you write it, comparing `data` as type `integer`):

```
if( data == '1' ){ //....
```

Comment: @ thanks code was correct the problem was on comparison data == '1' is correct .